# Log4j log file appending overwrite old events

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have an application that is using the log4j file appender to create a log file.  I need to import this log file into a log management system and its struggling with the RollingFileAppender setup which rolls the file over when it reaches 10mb

What I need is a log file that behaves in the same way as a windows event log with a maximum size and old events being overwritten.

Is this possible and if so, any suggestions on config?

Thanks

Comment: After some research I have found NTEventLogAppender so have set up logging to the windows application log.

Answer (score 0):

Have setup NTEventLogAppender

```
log4j.appender.wintel=org.apache.log4j.nt.NTEventLogAppender
log4j.appender.wintel.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.wintel.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %c %m%n
```